# Angular filter to initialise first name

Tags: angularjs, filter, initialization, names

I need to make an angular filter that will take full names, and initialise the first name, leaving only the last name, except in certain cases (e.g. Van Aanholt).

So the following:

```
Yohan Cabaye 
Oscar 
Jordi Alba Ramos 
Patrick Van Aanholt
Hatem Ben Arfa
```

Will be shown as:

```
Y. Cabaye
Oscar
J. Ramos
P. Van Aanholt
H. Ben Arfa
```

Any help would be appreciated.

---

UPDATE: This is what I've tried...

```
    angular.module('euroFilters', [])

              .filter('initialiseName', function() {

                        return function(name) {

var nameArr = name.split(' ');

var firstName = nameArr[0];
var firstNameInitial = nameArr[0][0] + ". ";

var lastName = nameArr[nameArr.length - 1];

var secondaryLastName = nameArr[nameArr.length - 2];

// If only one name (standard)...

if (nameArr.length <= 1) {
  return firstName;
}

// If more than one name, and contains "Van" or "Ben" (exception)...
else if (secondaryLastName === "Van" || secondaryLastName === "Ben") {
  return firstNameInitial + " " + secondaryLastName + " " + lastName;
}

// If more than one name (standard)...
else if (nameArr.length > 1) {
  return firstNameInitial + lastName;
}

};

});
```

Is there a more elegant way to write this? How would it convert into a `switch` statement, for example?

Comment: Update added - please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

You can use split and join for that. String are array like objects, so you can use index on them.

```js
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').filter('initialiseFirstName', function () {
  return function (name) {
    var parts = name.split(/\s+/);
    
    if (parts.length <= 1) {
      return name;
    }
    
    var first = parts[0][0] + '.';
    
    return first + ' ' + parts.slice(1).join(' ');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  {{'John Ket'|initialiseFirstName}}
</div>
```

Comment: This helped, but still haven't quite got it - can you see my update?

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need:

```
<div ng-app="app">
  {{'John Von Koten'|initialiseFirstName}}
</div>

<script>
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').filter('initialiseFirstName', function () {
function checkName(name){
        var prefixes = ['Van', 'Ben', 'Von'];
      for(var i = 0; i < prefixes.length; i++){
      if(name.indexOf(prefixes[i]) > 0){
      return true;
      }
      }
      return false;
  }

  return function (name) {
    var parts = name.split(/\s+/);

    if (parts.length <= 1) {
      return name;
    }

   if(parts.length > 2){ 
   if(checkName(name)){
     return parts[0][0] + '. ' + parts[1] + ' '+ parts[2];
    }
    }

    var first = parts[0][0] + '.';

    return first + ' ' + parts.slice(1).join(' ');
  }


});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. What's the purpose of the `/\s+/` part in the `.split()` method?

Comment: it's regex stating you want to split whenever there is 1 or more whitespaces in the string. (\s stands for whitespace, + means one or more)

Comment: Ok thanks. I tried it in JSFiddle and the prefixes part seems to be going wrong - it's returning 'undefined', and I can't figure out why - might be something to do with the `if(name.indexOf(prefixes[i]) > 0)` line? Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Paulos3000/rhba9w57/

Comment: Yea i noticed, i forgot the `var` in the for-loop. Change `for(i = 0; i < prefixes.length; i++)` to `for(var i = 0; i < prefixes.length; i++)`

Comment: Someone marked this down, not sure why. It may not be the most elegant solution out there, but it works for the purposes of this problem. Please justify.

Comment: Thanks, i guess the downvote was because it was not working or whatever.